# Why I have to provide account info to run mysqldump.exe through scheduled task in Windows 7

Tags: scheduled-tasks, mysql

I created a task in my Win7, to run php.exe. The command is: `C:\xampp\php\php.exe -q "C:\xampp\htdocs\creport\cleaner.php"`, and it works fine.

Then I created another task to run mysqldump.exe. The command is: `C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump.exe -u root -pvince c_report > C:\dbfiles\backup-"%DATE:/=-%.sql"`, but when creating the task a window popped  up asking for account information like:

[Sorry I don't have enough reputation to insert an image in my post]

Why is that? I mean, why are the two .exe files treated differently? And probably just because of that, I always failed to run mysqldump.exe though the task, it failed with last-run-result being 0x6.

Thanks a lot for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was fooled. I just found that the whether does the window pop up has nothing to do with which exe this task is scheduled to run. It comes up just because I has ticked option [Run whether user is logged on or not], therefore, in the case that user account is logged out, Windows need to store the password to log it in to run the task.